# card detail section doesn't reliably show on website checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, checkout, web-testing

I would be beyond words, extremely grateful is someone could please assist me (non- IT specialist).

On my online school booking page, the checkout inconsistently shows the option to insert card details. It does sometimes show this correctly, and I have received payments.

But now the checkout works irregularly, and mostly not at all. Sometimes it works temporarily after clearing the cache.

I've developed a website using a theme, added a booking plugin (Amelia), as well as a translation plugin (G translate).

I've recently deactivated ALL plugins minus Amelia, Hostinger, and Woo-Commerce. My issue persists.
I've been in touch with Amelia customer support, who are so painfully slow to reply to messages. One reply every 2 or 3 days.

Please can someone help me? I'm starting to be completely overwhelmed by this situation. I NEED this working before month end to receive payments.

I've tried deactivating all plugins.
I've tried customer support from Hostinger (say nothing from their end)
I've tried customer support G Translate (after website was given translation links when I first noticed the issue, but payments were not live yet - so this issue may have pre-existed) - say nothing from their end. They have insisted they will only continue to support me if I can prove the issue stops when I deactivate the plugin - which it doesn't. The issue is ongoing even when the translation plug in is deactivated.
I've tried customer support from Amelia - they say the issue is not their end, because no-one else has complained of an irregularity in the Card section of the checkout. They are horrendously slow to reply to messages.

Comment: Can you share the website URL to see the issue? Is it public?

Comment: https://corgienglish.fun/          Half way down the English page, you will find the booking form. Then randomly select until checkout.